# Matrix which commutes with permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, permutations

I'm trying to show that if $A$ commutes with all $3\times 3$ permutation matrices, then $A$ has to be of the following form: 
$ A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & b \\
b & a & b  \\
b & b & a  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$  What i've tried so far: Let $A$ be a general $3 \times 3$-Matrix. We are trying to find $A$ such that $AP = PA$. This equation basically means the following:
$AP$ is A with permuted columns. $PA$ is A with permuted rows. This means that $A$ has to be such that permuting columns and rows in the same way leaves the marix looking the same.

For example for the permutations which flip $1$ and $2$:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
d & e & f \\
a & b & c  \\
g & h & i  \\
\end{pmatrix}$ =
$
\begin{pmatrix}
b & a & c \\
e & d & f  \\
h & g & i  \\
\end{pmatrix}$. If we do the same for flipping $2$ and $3$ and flipping $1$ and $3$ we get three matrix equations for the 9 entries  $a$ to $i$ 
Resulting in the following equations: $a = i, b = h, g = c, f = d , b = d, a = e, c = f, h = g, b = c, f = h, i = e, g = d$ which means : $ a= e = i$ and $b=c=d=g=h$ which is exactly what I was looking for.

The thing now is. If I look at permutations which not only swap two rows/columns (for example $(123) \implies (312)$ ) I get equations which contradict my above equations.

What am I doing wrong? Is the proposition even true i.e. provable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh? The identity matrix is a permutation matrix and it commutes with every matrix, not only the ones you have mentioned.

Comment: Im not looking for a Permutation matrix that commutes with all other matrices. I'm looking for a general matrix A which commutes with all permutation matrices.

Comment: @user1551 I think he means non-trivial permutation matrices.

Comment: @user17574 That's not what you've literally said in the first sentence of your question (although I read what I expected to see, so didn't notice until the comment).

Comment: @MattPressland im pretty sure that's what I said, but I cleared it up. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @user17574 What I meant is, the statement that you are trying to prove is false. Let $P_3=I$. Then $P_3$ is a permutation matrix. Clearly, every matrix commutes with this $P_3$, including but not limited to the ones in the form of your $A$. Perhaps you meant to find all matrices that commute with *every* permutation matrix. If that is the case, you should correct your statement.

Comment: @user17574 Still not quite right - I think the problem is that you can't use the word "general" quite like that - there's no such thing as "a general permutation matrix", but there is such a thing as "all permutation matrices". I'll edit it and you can change it again if you're unhappy with my phrasing.

Comment: @user1551 Aaah I see! sorry, thanks for clearing that up!
MattPressland Thanks for the edit:) Looks good now

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check your calculation that gives you contradictory equations. In particular, if $P$ is the permutation matrix:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
then it acts on the right by applying $[3,1,2]$ to the columns, and on the left by applying $[2,3,1]$ to the rows, so you don't apply the same permutation to the rows and colums and compare the answers.

It is enough to consider only the permutation matrices that swap two rows/columns, as general permutation matrices are just products of these (this is the result "the symmetric group is generated by transpositions"). So for example, the permutation $1\mapsto 3$, $2\mapsto1$, $3\mapsto 2$ is just that given by swapping the first and second row/column and then swapping the second and third. As your $A$ commutes with both of these "swap matrices", it must commute with their product.

Comment: Even by observation though applying $P[3,1,2]$ to $A$ doesn't commute...unless I'm looking at it completely wrong.

Comment: @ZettaSuro You convinced me for a bit, but in fact it does - when you actually write it out you see that $P[3,1,2]$ acts on the right by applying the permutation $[3,1,2]$ to the columns, but on the left by applying the permutation $[2,3,1]$ to the rows. This is probably the source of the OP's confusion (and it confused me too) - only transpositions and the identity act by the "same" permutation on both sides. I now think my argument works (although Quimey's is better).

Comment: "As your A commutes with both of these "swap matrices", it must commute with their product." The problem with this statement though is that it's incorrect (I think) because even though each swap matrix commutes with $A$, they don't commute with each other, so you're applying them in reverse order on either side of the equation.

Comment: But that doesn't matter - what you want to prove is the third equation in your answer, and you can obtain that from the result for transpositions by commuting $A$ past one of the transpositions at a time, i.e. $P[2,1,3]P[3,2,1]A=P[2,1,3]AP[3,2,1]=AP[2,1,3]P[3,2,1]$. The problem from the failure of commutativity of the permutations is that you can't just apply the same permutation to the rows of $A$ and to the columns and compare the answers, because that doesn't correspond to multiplication by the same permutation matrix on each side.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: If $PA=AP$ and $QA=AQ$ then $(PQ)A = P(QA) = P(AQ) = (PA)Q = (AP)Q = A(PQ)$. In other words $C(A) = \{ P : PA=AP \}$ is closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

$$P[3,1,2]=P[2,1,3]P[3,2,1]$$

$$P[3,1,2]A=AP[3,1,2]$$

$$P[2,1,3]P[3,2,1]A=AP[2,1,3]P[3,2,1]$$

When you premultiply you're doing $[3,2,1]$ and then $[2,1,3]$. When you post multiply you're doing $[2,1,3]$ and then $[3,2,1]$, so your calculations only hold for a permutation matrix that can not be written as the product of two other permutation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The identity matrix commutes with all permutation matrices and the same is true for a matrix whose entries are all the same. Since your condition is linear in $A$ (if $A$ and $B$ permute with all $P$ then $A+B$ also commutes), any linear combination of those matrices will commute with permutation matrices.

This shows that your matrices commute with permutation matrices and the computation using transposition shows the converse.